# Train and test splits by unique dates, not observations, in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, partitioning, r-caret

I am trying to train a model with random forest in R. I have a timeseries containing information on multiple stocks per date, and have created a very simplified version of it:

```
Date <- rep(seq(as.Date("2009/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 100), 10)
Name <- c(rep("Stock A", 100), rep("Stock B",100), rep("Stock C", 100), rep("Stock D", 100), rep("Stock E",100), rep("Stock F",100), rep("Stock G",100), rep("Stock H",100), rep("Stock I", 100), rep("Stock J", 100))
Class <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=TRUE)

DF <- data.frame(Date, Name, Class)
DF <- DF %>% arrange(Date, Name)
```

Looks something like this:

```
        Date   Name    Class
1  2009-01-01  Stock A     5
2  2009-01-01  Stock B     2
3  2009-01-01  Stock C     4
4  2009-01-01  Stock D    10
5  2009-01-01  Stock E     7
6  2009-01-01  Stock F     3
...
11 2009-01-02  Stock A    10
12 2009-01-02  Stock B     8 
13 2009-01-02  Stock C     9
```

When using *trainControl* for the splitting of the data into training and testing periods, the split is done on the basis of each observation, but i would like to have it done based on unique days. What i have done until now is this:

```
timecontrol <- DF %>% group_by(Date) %>% trainControl(
  method            = 'timeslice',
  initialWindow     = 10,
  horizon           = 5,
  skip              = 4,
  fixedWindow       = TRUE,
  returnData        = TRUE, 
  classProbs        = TRUE
)

fitRF <- train(Class ~ ., 
               data = DF,
               method = "ranger",
               tuneGrid = tunegrid,
               na.action = na.omit,
               trControl = timecontrol)
```

This gives me a training set of 10 observations, followed by 5 testing observations. 
I would, however, like to have a training set(and testing..) containing all observations in 10 unique days, so that one training set would be 10 days times the number of observations each day, and with a skip between periods so that each testing period is on entirely new data (hence *skip=4*).

The first training/test split should be training=10 first unique days of data set, test=following 5 unique days, and then the second training/test split should be so that test set number 2 is the 5 days directly after the first test set.

Unlike the dataset i have shown above, my dataset contains different amounts of observations per day. My dataset contains 417497 observations, but only 2482 unique dates, so being able to make the training/testing splits based on the "grouped" dates makes a big difference.

Is there some way i can use trainControl and get the split that i need, or will I have to manually split all my data?

Comment: I don't think it can be done directly but you could make a summary df with the 2482 unique dates and use that for generating the splits. Then use the splits to get the appropriate indices of observations in the initial df. And then use these indices as `index` argument of `trainControl`. If this is not clear please post some data so I can show you with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your goal is to create block time series cross validation with dates as blocks.

One approach is to use `createTimeSlices` on the unique dates (in order) and then map that back to your data set:

```
dates <- unique(DF$Date) #already in order


slices <- createTimeSlices(dates,
                           initialWindow = 10,
                           horizon = 5,
                           skip = 4,
                           fixedWindow = TRUE)
```

map back these slices to the indexes in your original data:

```
slices <- lapply(slices, function(x){
  lapply(x, function(k){
    DF %>%
      mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
      filter(Date %in% dates[k]) %>%
      pull(n)
  })
})
```

so the first train data frame will be:

```
DF[slices$train[[1]],]
```

while the testing data will be:

```
DF[slices$test[[1]],]
```

now when defining trainControl use the obtained train and test indexes:

```
tr <- trainControl(returnData = TRUE, 
                   classProbs = TRUE,
                   index = slices$train,
                   indexOut = slices$test)
```

data:

```
Date <- rep(seq(as.Date("2009/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 100), 10)
Name <- c(rep("Stock A", 100), rep("Stock B",100), rep("Stock C", 100), rep("Stock D", 100), rep("Stock E",100), rep("Stock F",100), rep("Stock G",100), rep("Stock H",100), rep("Stock I", 100), rep("Stock J", 100))
Class <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=TRUE)

DF <- data.frame(Date, Name, Class)
DF <- DF %>% arrange(Date, Name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @missuse! I didn't get it to work at first, but realized that my dataset was grouped by Name from my feature creation, and after ungrouping it looks perfect :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. This type of resampling where observations are held together is called block resampling. The general way to perform it is to take the unique blocks, create resamples on them and map back to the original data. If the answer solved your problem then I suggest [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I will delete my comments regarding the question edits I suggest you do the same.